# Additional Emulator Command Line Options is not showing on my eclipse?

Tags: java, android

Additional Emulator Command Line Options is not in my eclipse, why, and how can i add it?
I need it for creating sd card for emulator in android.

Answer (score 0):

What about JVM Options box in the Exlipse run/debug configuration? Or what do you need, could you tell more concrete.

Comment: How can I create an SDCARD from my eclipse and to use it on emulator in android?